# CSV data to Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a CSV file:

```
r1,s1,1
r1,s2,1
r1,s3,2
r1,s4,2
r2,s1,2
r2,s2,2
r2,s3,1
```

etc.

I want to have a dictionary that can store as follows:

r1 is the key for another dictionary. And third column is (numbers) are they keys for another dictionary. So I want to write the CSV data as follows,

```
dictionarystuff = {r1: {1: [s1, s2], 2: [s3, s4]},
                   r2: {1: [s3], 2:[S1, s2]}
                   }
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: @dvm I do not have a direction on this and that is why I am asking the question here.

Comment: You just have to loop you CSV file, check if the first field is set in the dictionary, if not, create a object with the number associated to it. If it already exists go incrementing the list associated with the dictionary inside the dictionary.

Comment: Or use either the `setdefault` method or a `collections.defaultdict` so you don't have to worry about checking if it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` of `dict`s, make use of `setdefault()` and have a list for every dict key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = """\
r1,s1,1
r1,s2,1
r1,s3,2
r1,s4,2
r2,s1,2
r2,s2,2
r2,s3,1
"""

d = defaultdict(dict)

for line in data.split():
    a, b, c = line.split(",")
    d[a].setdefault(int(c), []).append(b)

d = dict(d)
print(d)
```

**Result:**

```
{'r1': {1: ['s1', 's2'], 2: ['s3', 's4']}, 'r2': {1: ['s3'], 2: ['s1', 's2']}}
```

The `defaultdict` is converted to regular dict for nicer printing, otherwise it looks like:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'r1': {1: ['s1', 's2'], 2: ['s3', 's4']}, 'r2': {1: ['s3'], 2: ['s1', 's2']}})
```